# How secure is the password from the hash sum (SHA-512) of a long sentence

Tags: passwords, sha-512

If I convert a long sentence (>50 characters) to c and use the result (128 hex characters) as a password, how secure is it?

Answer (score 5):

The result would be as strong as the sentence itself; the order of trying all possible "long sentence $s$" is precisely as high as trying all hashes over that sentence $H(s)$.

There is a small benefit in the sense that hackers would probably not perform the hash before entering it in the password field. Of course, if somebody finds out that you are using the hash algorithm before entering it then that advantage disappears; that an algorithm should not depend on a global secret or the algorithm itself is known as Kerckhoff's principle.

---

One advantage of hashing the password is that it would be relatively hard to get the password if a database of such passwords is found. That won't help you if you use the hash to directly login to a page though, as the hash is now basically the password.

On servers passwords are usually hashed using a *password hash* or *PBKDF* designed to add a not-insignificant amount of time for each password to try. Usually that requires something in the range of $2^{20}$ operations. Other options like Password Authenticated Key Establishment (PAKE) algorithms such as SRP could also be used.

Comment: You write the hash would be as strong as the sentence itself. That is not correct. A sentence with 128 words is safer than one string with 128 hex chars.

Comment: @dan-ros No, that's not correct. It is not possible to brute force a 512 bit hash, the only way to guess that hash is by iterating over all the possible input values. Anything that offers 128 bit or higher security is unbreakable in practice.

Answer (score 2):

**Sentence from all books (Bad Way)**

First some statistics. Let's assume that

1. We have a total of [156264880](https://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/literature/how-many-books.htm) printed books and that is $< 2^{24}$.
2. The [average word usage in a sentence is around 15](https://prowritingaid.com/Sentence-Length-Average)
3. The [average word size is 5.1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=average%20english%20word%20length).
4. There are 15 such sentences on average per page (no ref).
5. There are an average of 100 pages per book (no ref).

Now let's sum up all; we have $~2^{42}$ different choices for a sentence from all possible books. **This is quite a small space for password selection.**

Consider 8x GTX 1080 which can have 8624.7 MH/s for SHA-512 that can reach $2^{33}$ for seconds. So testing all is not hard for capable attackers. The real security of your password now relies on the password hashing algorithm applied on the system or [maybe none as Facebook did.](https://www.theverge.com/2019/3/21/18275837/facebook-plain-text-password-storage-hundreds-millions-users). If it is good like increasing the cost like $2^{20}$ with iteration you will get at most $~2^{62}$ password security. Well, why trust a system with an unknown design while we can do better?

**Sentence from your books (Very bad way)**

1. You might have posted your all books online some time ago and you may have forgotten it.
2. You purchased all of your books online.
3. You put your book on the desk and while online meeting the book is captured.
4. Three letter agencies visited your home and made the list of your books.

And, so on. **The proposed method is in some sense security with obscurity**. Once the attacker has some more knowledge then they can reduce the already small space into a much smaller space.

**Hash doesn't increase entropy**

Entropy is the property of the source and hash functions cannot increase the entropy, for this one needs to change/modify the source.

**Word from a predetermined list : Dicewire - Bip-39 (The correct way)**

1. Take a list of $7776=6^5$ words ( [dicewire](https://www.eff.org/dice) has this amount and this is $\approx 2^{14}$ )
2. Roll a dice 5 times, multiply the dice values, and select a word from the list.
3. Repeat step 2 $x$-times
4. Write the words in order as your passwords.

How much strength we can get;

| $x$ | strength in Bits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 13.924 |
| 2 | 26.849 |
| 3 | 39.774 |
| 4 | 52.699 |
| 5 | 65.624 |
| 6 | 78.554 |
| 7 | 91.473 |
| 8 | 104.398 |
| 9 | 117.323 |
| 10 | 130.248 |

As we can see, with 4 we can pass the bad way. As a bonus, we exactly know how strong our passwords are independent of any system.

Comment: "multiply them": I’m not sure that’s the correct term for the operation. Also, this should be done in base 6, not the default base 10. "concatenate" might be better.

Comment: Maybe I should say multiply the dice values. I don't use base 6, I use base 2 so that we can talk about the key space, for example with 10 words one can be sure that they have AES-128 bits.

Comment: @A.Hersean we multiply the dice values to get the word index then we can write or concatenate the words as passwords.

Comment: One of my colleagues suggested the wording "read the values of the dices as one number of 5 digits".

Comment: @A.Hersean It is possible to read them in that way and construct a mapping; concat the dice values and look at the table. Once the table is constructed in the corresponding way (a unique index other than the row number), it might be faster than the multiplication and the usual ordering from 1 to $6^5$ ( well we do this not on the server so my solar-based calculator can handle this). Keep in mind that, that is not exactly base6 representation since base6's canonical representation is from 0 to 5. So, we need a substruct one to be on the base6.